# Nvidia 3d vision kit and unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, nvidia, stereo-3d

There are some scripts for creating stereoscopic 3d in Unity3d, you can find an example in this [link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/63874-stereo-3D-in-Unity-3D). This stereokopix3D.js works great for anaglyph rendering, you can adjust any stereo parameter in this script.

I'm wondering that if there are similar packages which will work for Nvidia 3d vision kit and its shutter glasses (for Windows). Any exe file is seen by Nvidia's shutter glasses (since exe is working on DirectX automatically like any other commercial 3d games) but what I'm looking for is a script/package to create stereo vision (like how stereokopix3D.js creates anaglyph) in order to work on stereo part.

[This link](http://wiki.etc.cmu.edu/unity3d/index.php/Stereoscopic_3D) seems to state that since stereoscopic 3d system is external to Unity, you have no control over how the 3D effect is interpreted while using Nvidia 3d vision system; so there are no way to use Nvidia system. On the other hand, I'm still not so sure about this :)

I also have tried to change stereo parameters usıng Nvidia SDK. I exposed required functions into DLL to use in Unity. However, DLL has not worked properly, I could not reach functions in SDK for some reason that I don't get. If there is a way to use SDK functions in Unity, I would be so glad to learn this way too.

In addition, if there are any other alternatives instead of anaglyph rendering for creating stereo vision, I will be glad to hear them too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This plugin allows you to use two cameras in your scene to compose a true stereoscopic 3D vision:

http://u3d.as/content/dembeta-sl/active-stereoscopic-3d-for-unity/2Vt

Comment: Thanks Edy, I will look at it! Have you ever tried this plugin in your applications? Is it possible to change parameters like distance between cameras etc. by script?